# How do you prove something is a sigma-algebra using the definition?

Tags: measure-theory

Ok, granted. I've come to the realisation that I'm actually not that strong in math. I want to learn though so i hope you can help me with this problem. I'm struggling in a measure theory course and I'm trying hard but i continue to get the basics wrong. I hope you can help me with a step by step proces on how to do this...

I have to prove that this system is a $\mathcal{E}:=\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}:B \text { or }B^c \text{ countable}\}$ using the definition.

For $(\sigma1)$ i am thinking, that we can "substitute" $\mathbb{R}$ for $B$ in the condition. Thus we find that $\mathbb{R}^c=\{\emptyset \}.$ So it follows that $\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{E}$ since $\{\emptyset \}$ is countable.

For $(\sigma2)$ and $(\sigma3)$ i have no idea how to start or grasp the ideas.

I'm using this definition:

$(\sigma1):X\in\mathcal{E}$

$(\sigma2):$ For all sets $A$ in $\mathcal{E}$ it follows that$A^c\in\mathcal{E}$.

$(\sigma3):$ If $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of set from $\mathcal{E}$ then it follows that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}^{n} A_n\in\mathcal{E}$

Comment: This is actually very simple, you just have to start and use what you got. Assume that $A \in \mathcal{E}$. We want to show that $A^c \in \mathcal{E}$. $A \in \mathcal{E}$ means that either $A$ or $A^c$ is countable. Can you proceed?

Comment: I did think about this. Here is my take: If $B\in \mathcal{E} \rightarrow$ $B$ or $B^c$ is countable. If $B$ is countable then the condition is satisfied immediately. If $B^c$ is countable the condition is also satisfied.... And then i don't know. Does it follow that $B^c\in \mathcal{E},$ Why? is that the case?

Comment: If either $B$ or $B^c$ is countable, then either $B^c$ or $(B^c)^c = B$ is countable and so $B^c \in \mathcal{E}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let this be a detailed answer.

Here, $X=\mathbb{R}.$

For $(\sigma1),$ we need to show that $X \in \mathcal{E}.$

**Claim:** $X=\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{E}.$

**Reason:** Because, $\mathbb{R}^c=\varnothing$ and $\varnothing$ is countable.

So, $(\sigma1)$ is verified.

For $(\sigma2),$ we need to show that $A^c \in \mathcal{E}$ whenever $A \in \mathcal{E}.$

Say we have that $A \in \mathcal{E}.$ Here, we have two cases.

**Case 1:**

> Say $A$ is countable. For $A^c \in \mathcal{E},$ we need $A^c$ to be countable or $(A^c)^c$ to be countable. See that $(A^c)^c=A$ is countable, even though $A^c$ is uncountable. So, we have that $A^c \in \mathcal{E}.$

**Case 2:**

> Say $A^c$ is countable. For $A^c \in \mathcal{E},$ we need $A^c$ to be countable or $(A^c)^c$ to be countable. However, $A^c$ is countable. So, we need not bother about $(A^c)^c.$ So, here also, we have that $A^c \in \mathcal{E}.$

So, $(\sigma2)$ is verified.

For $(\sigma3),$ we need $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \in \mathcal{E}$ whenever $\{A_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{E}.$

For each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $A_n \in \mathcal{E}$ means that either $A_n$ or $A_n^c$ is countable.

We have three cases here.

**Case 1:**

> Say $A_n$ is countable for each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is a countable union of countable sets which is again countable.
> So,  $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \in \mathcal{E}.$

**Case 2:**

> Say $A_n$ is uncountable for each $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is a countable union of uncountable sets which is uncountable. Now by De Morgan's laws, we have that $$\bigg(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\bigg)^c= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n^c,$$ which is countable intersection of countable sets.
> So,  $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \in \mathcal{E}.$

**Case 3:**

> Say we have that $A_n$ is countable for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A_m$ is uncountable for some $m \in \mathbb{N}.$ Bifurcate them and define as follows:
> Let
> $$B_n=
>     \begin{cases}
>         A_n & \text{if $A_n$ is countable} \\
>         \varnothing & \text{if $A_n$ is uncountable} \\
>     \end{cases}
> $$
> and
> $$C_n=
>     \begin{cases}
>         A_n & \text{if $A_n$ is uncountable} \\
>         \varnothing & \text{if $A_n$ is countable } \\
>     \end{cases}
> $$
> Now, from Case $1$ and Case $2,$ we have that $B,C \in \mathcal{E},$ where $B=\cup B_n,C=\cup C_n.$
> We just need to show that $B \cup C \in \mathcal{E}.$
> See that $B$ is countable and $C^c$ is countable.
> Now, we have that $$B \cup C= (B^c \cap C^c)^c = \big((\mathbb{R}\backslash B) \cap C^c \big)= \big( C^c \cap (\mathbb{R}\backslash B) \big) = (C^c \cap \mathbb{R}) \backslash (C^c \cap B) $$ is countable.
> So,  $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \in \mathcal{E}.$

So, $(\sigma3)$ is verified.

We have verified all the three conditions.

Therefore, $\mathcal{E}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb{R}.$

We are done and I rest!